# og:description not getting shown

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have updated the og:description tag along with other tags for [this](https://www.demacmedia.com/ecommerce/ecommerce-free-shipping-profitability/) page. The debugger shows this in the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) but does not show it in the preview neither when I share it on Facebook. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: why is og:description 2 times in the code? also, og:title.

Comment: @luschn: Using a plugin to do the job. Disabled the option in previous post and installed a new plugin.

Comment: make sure it´s there only one time

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem: everything looked good in the Sharing Debugger preview information (meaning all image and description info was showing as correct), but the "Link Preview" area did not show the "Description" excerpt for the page (just the image and title).

After some trial and error, I discovered the problem was in the Title: apparently Facebook has a limit of around 63 characters or so for the `og:title` property (I was dynamically fetching title data from the DB, and some titles ran long). Once I limited the length of the page title to a max no. of characters of around 63, everything was good!

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. One more thing I noticed for horizontal images (1200x630 px or 400x225 px) that if the og:title characters are less than 63, even then og:description is displayed only in one line, other characters in og:description are truncated. That's why rather to use a horizontal image (1200x630 px) it is better to use a vertical image. (ideally in 2:1 ratio) So that it shows a full og:title (even its length is > 63 characters) and multiple lines in og:description.

Comment: I'm not sure if the image dimensions would affect this (but if you say it did.... seems kind of odd, but could be another FB API vagary). Visually, typically you want to have square images actually, and at least 500x500 (for Facebook).

Comment: Another thing I noticed here was that the size of the IMAGE NAME can also have an effect on the output of the link preview. If the image name is too long, this can also chop/remove the description text.

Comment: you wanna say image name or the length of <og:title> tag? So far as per my experience, if og:title is more than 63 characters, including white spaces, then the og:description is omitted, (but image name doesn’t affect og:description

Comment: Had the same problem (cost me a few hours). My title was longer than 63 - cut and works now. I have found no information in the FB description, that the length is limited to 63 :-(

Comment: Same problem. Facebook still inserts the description in the share dialog, but it has a maximum height set with hidden overflow, so the description drops off. Depending on screen size, it will show it, however the share box does have a maximum width. After sharing one with a dropped description, it still did show later in larger desktop sizes.

Answer (score -7):

Have you tried it like this?

`<meta property="og:description" content="bla-bla"/>`

Comment: well...what´s different to his current og tag(s)? i assume you did not check out his page source?